# Android write string to file takes too long

Tags: android, kotlin, java-io

I use the following function to write a long string (byte array size is 871504) to the internal storage of an Android device, but it takes around one and a half minute to complete. However, for another string (byte array size is 782979), it just takes a few seconds to complete.

```
fun saveTempSrc(data: String, ctx: Context) {
    try {
        val dataByteArray = data.toByteArray()
        Timber.d("saveTempSrc: byte array size = %d", dataByteArray.size)
        val inputStream = BufferedInputStream(ByteArrayInputStream(dataByteArray))
        val outputStream = BufferedOutputStream(ctx.openFileOutput("example.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE))
        inputStream.copyTo(outputStream)
        inputStream.close()
        outputStream.flush()
        outputStream.close()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        Timber.e(e, "Write Temp file failed")
    }
}
```

Is this function suitable for writing long string to file? I run this function in RxJava's I/O scheduler.

Comment: Why are you converting that string to byte array?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use FileWriter.

```
val sdcard = ctx.getExternalStorageDirectory()
val file = File("example.txt", sdcard)
val fileWriter = FileWriter(file)
fileWriter.write(data)
fileWriter.flush()
fileWriter.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that the long waiting time is not due to file I/O but due to Regex find with a very long string before writing file.